# Finding connected components of adjacency matrix graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, matrix, graph-theory

I have a random graph represented by an adjacency matrix in Java, how can I find the connected components (sub-graphs) within this graph?

I have found BFS and DFS but not sure they are suitable, nor could I work out how to implement them for an adjacency matrix.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is the adjacency matrix stored? Additional trickery can be used for some data formats.

Answer (score 23):

You need to allocate marks - int array of length n, where n is the number of vertex in graph and fill it with zeros. Then:

1) For BFS do the following:

```
Components = 0;

Enumerate all vertices, if for vertex number i, marks[i] == 0 then

    ++Components;

    Put this vertex into queue, and 

    while queue is not empty, 

        pop vertex v from q

        marks[v] = Components;

        Put all adjacent vertices with marks equal to zero into queue.
```

2) For DFS do the following.

```
Components = 0;

Enumerate all vertices, if for vertex number i, marks[i] == 0 then

    ++Components;

    Call DFS(i, Components), where DFS is

    DFS(vertex, Components)
    {
        marks[vertex] = Components;
        Enumerate all vertices adjacent to vertex and 
        for all vertex j for which marks[j] == 0
            call DFS(j, Components);
    }
```

After performing any of this procedures, Components will have number of connected components,
and for each vertex i, marks[i] will represent index of connected component i belongs.

Both complete on O(n) time, using O(n) memory, where n is matrix size. But I suggest you BFS as far as it doesn't suffer from stack overflow problem, and it doesn't spend time on recursive calls.

BFS code in Java:

```java
  public static boolean[] BFS(boolean[][] adjacencyMatrix, int vertexCount, int givenVertex){
      // Result array.
      boolean[] mark = new boolean[vertexCount];

      Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
      queue.add(givenVertex);
      mark[givenVertex] = true;

      while (!queue.isEmpty())
      {
        Integer current = queue.remove();

        for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; ++i)
            if (adjacencyMatrix[current][i] && !mark[i])
            {
                mark[i] = true;
                queue.add(i);
            }
      }

      return mark;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Given adjacencyMatrix[x][y] if and only if there is a path between x and y.
      boolean[][] adjacencyMatrix = new boolean[][]
              {
                      {false,true,false,false,false},
                      {true,false,false,true,true},
                      {false,false,false,false,false},
                      {true,false,false,false,false},
                      {true,false,false,false,false}
              };
      // Mark[i] is true if and only if i belongs to the same connected component as givenVertex vertex does.
      boolean[] mark = BFS(adjacencyMatrix, 5, 0);

      for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
          System.out.println(mark[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, I've realised my original question wasn't too clear. I need to find the connected component (so other reachable vertices) for a given vertex. I realise this is probably similar but I can't visualise it, could you give me a similar pseudo code?

Comment: All you need is to drop top enumeration circle, and start from Components = 1:

1) For BFS you need to put your given vertex into queue and follow the algorithm.

2) For DFS just call DFS(your vertex, 1).

After that for all vertices i belongs to the same connected component as your given vertex you will have marks[i] == 1, and marks[i] == 0 for others.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean by dropping the top enumeration circle, do you mind writing it again? Thanks. Also which is best to use for this problem BFS or DFS?

Comment: When I said "drop", I meant that is redundant in your case, you don't have to write it. Read the last two lines I've add to the original answer, I suggest you to use BFS.

Comment: I see, thanks. Do you mind adding the exact code? I think it should help me a lot.

Comment: @Wisdom'sWind, just a little note, the complexity of the algorithm is `O(max(|V|,|E|)`.

Comment: This BFS/DFS is for adjacency matrix (as was asked). When I said it's O(n) I meant n is matrix size. 

True BDS/DFS complexity is O(max(|V|,|E|)) but it's for case when you store edges in a lists.

Comment: @Wisdom'sWind, if by "matrix size" you mean number of nodes squared, yes.

Comment: All that effort and the asker never even marked the answer... some people are rude! +1 @Wisdom'sWind

Answer (score 3):

You can implement DFS iteratively with a stack, to eliminate the problems of recursive calls and call stack overflow. The implementation is very similar to BFS with queue - you just have to mark vertices when you pop them, not when you push them in the stack.

Answer (score 3):

Using scipy's sparse module,

Assuming your input is a dictionary from a `(label_1,label_2)` to `weight`
you can run this code:

```
vertices, edges = dict2graph(cooccur_matrix, edge_threshold)
n, components = sparse.csgraph.connected_components(edges, directed=False)
print ('Found {n} components'.format(n=n))
components = collect_components(components,vertices)
components = [c for c in components if len(c)>=component_threshold]
print ('removed {k} small components'.format(k=n-len(components)))
print ('component sizes: '+ repr([len(c) for c in components]))
```

See full gist on github [here](https://gist.github.com/urigoren/f073f1c9e19323ada795d2963aa698a2)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to `sparse.csgraph.connected_components`! Super helpful.